# Sorting a vector based on the values

Tags: r

Let say I have below vector

```
vec = c('1d', '3m', '5d', '10y', '1m')
```

here, `m` means months, `d` means day, and `y` means year. I want to sort the vector in ascending order of day, month, and year. So ideally the sorted vector will be -

```
c('1d', '5d', '1m', '3m', '10y')
```

Is there any way to achieve this using R's base libraries (I am restricted to download contributed packages).

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Does the real data have combined entrees, like `1d3m`? Or is it always number-letter?

Comment: No. It is always number-letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract `d`, `m` and `y` value separately and extract the number separately. Create a vector of `correct_order` that you want, use `match` to get corresponding number and use it in `order`.

```
vec = c('1d', '3m', '5d', '10y', '1m')
correct_order <- c('d', 'm', 'y')

vec[order(match(gsub('\\d', '', vec), correct_order), 
          as.numeric(gsub('\\D', '', vec)))]

#[1] "1d"  "5d"  "1m"  "3m"  "10y"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_replace`

```
library(stringr)
vec[order(sapply(str_replace_all(vec, setNames( c('*1', '*30', '*365'), 
    c('d', 'm', 'y'))), function(x) eval(parse(text = x))))]
#[1] "1d"  "5d"  "1m"  "3m"  "10y"
```

---

Or an option with `separate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tibble(vec) %>% 
   separate(vec, into = c('v1', 'v2'), sep='(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)',
         convert = TRUE, remove = FALSE) %>% 
   arrange(v2, v1) %>%
   pull(vec)
#[1] "1d"  "5d"  "1m"  "3m"  "10y"
```

---

Or can also use a matching with a named vector to `order`

```
vec[order(readr::parse_number(vec) * 
  (setNames(c(1, 7, 30, 365), c('d', 'w', 'm', 'y'))[str_remove(vec, '\\d+')]))]
#[1] "1d"  "5d"  "1m"  "3m"  "10y"
```

#### data

```
vec <- c('1d', '3m', '5d', '10y', '1m')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the lexical order of `d`, `m` and `y` is `d < m < y` already, you can try the code below

```
> vec[order(gsub("\\d+", "", vec), as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", vec)))]
[1] "1d"  "5d"  "1m"  "3m"  "10y"
```